# A Python function that takes how many rows and how many columns it should print pair of empty square brackets [] in grid form

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I was trying to do my homework and ı stuck at 10th question.

I do not understand where is my mistake :(

our teacher want this;

```
>>> print_grid( 5, 3 )
[][][]
[][][]
[][][]
[][][]
[][][]

>>> print_grid( 4, 7 )
[][][][][][][]
[][][][][][][]
[][][][][][][]
[][][][][][][]
```

and there is my function;

```
    def first(column ):
    print("[]",end="") 
    for i in range(column-4):
        print("[]",end="")   
    print("[]") 



def second(column):
    print("[]", end="") 
    for i in range(column-7): 
        print("[]",end ="") 



def grid(column,raw): 
    first(column) 
    for i in range(raw):  
        for i in range(2):
            second(column) 

        first(column)

grid(5,3)
```

my output;

```
[][][]
[][][][][]
[][][][][]
[][][][][]
```

and why is this printed out?

How can ı make it look like more beautifully :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary code in your solution.  You are printing `rows` * `cols` elements, so you should only need two nested loops here.  Having multiple functions that loop more times than necessary will make this code hard to maintain, as well as hard to read.

Next, you shouldn't be doing any arithmetic on your row and column indices.  The `column-4` and `row-7` just don't make sense, unless you are trying to print a more complex pattern, which doesn't seem to be the case.

You are on the right track with your print statements that have `end=""`, since by default a newline will be printed that you don't want.  An alternative to printing would be building a string and printing explicitly at the end.

Here are two possible options:

---

For a solution that explicitly "prints":

```
def grid_print(x, y):
  for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
      print('[]', end='')
    print()
```

However, it might be more useful to build a string of the grid, and return *that* from the function.

```
def grid_string(x, y):
  return '\n'.join('[]' * y for _ in range(x))
```

---

```
>>> grid_print(3, 5)
[][][][][]
[][][][][]
[][][][][]

>>> print(grid_string(2, 6))
[][][][][][]
[][][][][][]
```